# How do i fetch first key value pair (i.e., 'type': 45) from a dictionary which contains key as list with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
{'alarms': [{'date': '20170925T235525-0700',
             'id': 8,
             'ip': '172.26.70.4',
             'severity': 4,
             'type': 45},
            {'date': '20170925T235525-0700',
             'id': 7,
             'ip': '172.26.70.4',
             'severity': 4,
             'type': 45},
            {'date': '20170925T235525-0700',
             'id': 6,
             'ip': '172.26.70.4',
             'severity': 4,
             'type': 45},
            {'date': '20170925T220858-0700',
             'id': 5,
             'ip': '172.26.70.4',
             'severity': 6,
             'type': 44},
            {'date': '20170925T220857-0700',
             'id': 4,
             'ip': '172.26.70.4',
             'severity': 6,
             'type': 44},
            {'date': '20170925T220857-0700',
             'id': 3,
             'ip': '172.26.70.4',
             'severity': 6,
             'type': 44},
            {'date': '20170925T220856-0700',
             'id': 2,
             'severity': 6,
             'type': 32},
            {'date': '20170925T220850-0700', 'id': 1, 'severity': 6, 'type': 1},
            {'date': '20170925T220850-0700',
             'id': 0,
             'severity': 6,
             'type': 33}]}
```

Need to fetch first key value pair (i.e., 'type': 45)

Kindly guide, I am trying it on Python 2.7.

Comment: How is `'type': 45` the first one? It's behind several others.

Comment: @StefanPochmann : My question should have been - How to fetch 'type' and corresponding value (for eg: 'type': 45) from dictionary of a list of dictionaries based on latest date. :)

I am not able to edit !!

Comment: What do you mean you're not able to edit it?

Comment: @StefanPochmann : when i try to edit the headline and try to save, it says - It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a dictionary where the `"alarms" key is associated with a list of dictionaries.

That dictionary is in the list associated with the `"alarms"` key. So you can fetch it with:

```
data['alarms'][0]
```

with `data` the variable that stores this structure. So:

```
>>> data['alarms'][0]
{'date': '20170925T235525-0700', 'severity': 4, 'id': 8, 'ip': '172.26.70.4', 'type': 45}
```

Comment: data['alarms'][0] is a list and not dictionary

Comment: @ddor254: no, `data['alarms']` is a list, `data['alarms'][0]` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do :

```
def return_correct_dict(data):
    for d in data['alarms']:
        if d.get('type',"") == 45:
            return d
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary of a list of dictionaries. 
Suppose your dictionary is stored in a variable named **dict**.

```
dict['alarm'][0]['type'] will give you the value 45.
```